# Extracting zeros from numpy array and creating a new raster

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

The following code reads in several .tif files from an input folder, converts them to numpy arrays and adds them together. All input files are binary:

```
inputFolder = "/home/usr/Desktop/BufferFolder/"
outputFolder = "/home/usr/Desktop//BufferFolder/Addition"
template = gdal.Open("/home/usr/Desktop//BufferFolder/Template.tif")
rows = template.RasterYSize 
cols = template.RasterXSize
if template is None: 
print 'Unable to open template file' 
    sys.exit(1) 
templateArray = np.array(template.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray())  
mainArray = 0 * templateArray

os.chdir(inputFolder)

def findRasters(path, filter):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path, filter):
        for file in fnmatch.filter(files, filter):
            yield os.path.join(root, file)

count = 0 
for raster in findRasters(inputFolder, '*.tif'):
    (infilepath, infilename) = os.path.split(raster)
    openraster = gdal.Open(infilename)
    rasterToArray = np.array(openraster.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray())
    mainArray = mainArray + rasterToArray 
    count = count + 1
```

I am interested in the 0 values from `mainArray`. How can I output these values into a separate raster in the `outputFolder`?

Comment: Do you mean something like mask does?http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.generic.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below should work.  The key part is the assignment `d[(mainArray == 0)] = 0` setting all the items to zero in a new array where mainArray is zero.  Sounds like your rasters might be spatial so the projection setting stuff is important too.

```
#
# ----- create output raster
#
outfilename = outputFolder + '/zeros.tif'
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff")
output = driver.Create(outfilename, cols, rows, 1, gdal.GDT_Byte)
if output is None:
    sys.exit("Unable to create raster " + outfilename)

#
# ----- set output projection to the same as the template
#
output.SetGeoTransform(template.GetGeoTransform())
output.SetProjection(template.GetProjection())

#
# ----- create output array of all ones to match the template
#
d = np.ones((rows, cols), np.uint8)

#
# ----- change 1 to 0 in output array where mainArray is 0
#
d[(mainArray == 0)] = 0

print "Number of zeros in mainArray = %d" % (mainArray == 0).sum()
print "Number of zeros in output array = %d" % (d == 0).sum()

#
# ----- write and close output file
#
output.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(d)
output = None
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I used your code with the following modification" d[(mainArray != 0)] = 0 and I got what I wanted